# Conditional binding: apply binding only if some criteria met

Tags: knockout.js

Is there a way to apply one binding in knockout if some criteria are met and do not apply this binding if those critera are not met?

```html
<div data-bind="custombinding: $data.values"></div>
```

I need to apply this binding if `$data.canEdit` is true, otherwise I do not need to apply this binding.

The exact example is more complicated.

Comment: what does it mean to apply or not to apply? does it have to do with visibility? does it have to do with the elements being created? Please, elaborate your question a little bit. It's not clear what you want to do. If you explain it clearly, I'm sure someone will help you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think you should typically make different bindings dependent on eachother. Instead, create a dependency on logical view model properties (which allows you to easily unit test involved logic too). You already mention you have such a property: `canEdit`, a boolean observable I'd assume.

If you do, you could create custom bindings that go like this:

```html
<div data-bind="custombinding: { onlyIf: canEdit, vals: values }"></div>
```

In addition I also second @JeremyBarnes' suggestion (using an `if` binding), e.g.:

```html
<!-- ko if: canEdit -->
<div data-bind="custombinding: values"></div>
<!-- /ko -->
```

Furthermore, if you must, you can include something like this in your view:

```html
<div data-bind="custombinding: !!canEdit() ? values : []"></div>
```

As a side note I'd suggest encapsulating that ternary operator's logic in a computed observable.

---

However, going directly to the question asked, if you check [the custom binding documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings.html) you can find that you could probably do what you want, because binding handlers have access to:

- `allBindings` for that particular element; as well as
- `bindingContext.$data` to access the view model (and e.g. find `canEdit` through that)

It's impossible to give more precise answers or guidance, as your question is rather low on details.

Answer (score 1):

[Try the knockout if-binding.](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/if-binding.html)

That binding leaves out the HTML if the condition is not met (the div would be excluded).

Otherwise, you'll want to bind it to an object in the JS that is conditionally set up.

Comment: I know this solutionm, but I do not like it, because logic is more complicated. Div in example is wrapper and there is a lot of logic inside it. I need all staff that is inside this div. If-binding would be usable for simple visibility, but not in this case.